# Jdbc statement error

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-security

I have problem with such simple thing, sql statement, I have table in database that contains link in varchar(255), people are logged to site by links, so I'm taking logged person name (Getting something like http://something.site.com) and then passing it to method in which I'm query database to get all records where my logged user has entries.

```
jdbcTemplate.query("Select * from HIRE where USER=(?)",new Object[] { userName },
```

However it gives no results at all. I have checked the value in HIRE and the userName are exactly the same, what have I missed?

Comment: What is the version of mysql that you are using ?

Comment: It is hsqldb database

Comment: Remove `()` around question mark. `select * from HIRE where USER=?`